# How to position a non-fixed div after a fix div?

Tags: html, css

I have a menu div that is fixed to the top and below the menu div is a non-fixed navigation bar.
The menu height is dynamic, it means it will change according to its content. Especially when changing the window size, the menu may change it height. Thus, simply adding a `margin-top` to the navbar is no solution:

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.menu {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background-color:yellow;
    top:0;
}
.navbar{
  margin-top:50px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
        Menu
</div>
<div class="navbar">
    Article
</div>
```

The closest solution that I found for a dynamic menu height is mentioned in this [blog entry](https://grobmeier.solutions/div-starting-after-fixed-div-28082015.html). The author has a menu height given in % and just adds a wrapper around in with the same height that is in the flow again.

So its simply:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.landing {
    height: 80%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}

.landing-wrapper {
    height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="landing-wrapper">
    <div class="landing">
        Could be an image
    </div>
</div>
<div class="article">
    Article
</div>
```

However, in my case, the menu has neither a fixed height in pixels nor in %. Is there any other solution for this using only CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `position: sticky`?

You would not need to juggle with the margin, as the element is not taken out of the context.

Check the following snippet:

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.menu {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    position: sticky;
    background-color:yellow;
    top:0;
}
.navbar{
  height: 200px;
  background-color:green;
}

.container {
  height: 1500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    Menu that should wrap and make container bigger
</div>
<div class="navbar">
    Article
</div>
<div class="container"></div>
```